# Can we call a function from view page in rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I've a function/method defined with name `"check_is_null"` under the file `condition.rb` in rails-root/bin folder which checks whether the provided array is null or not and returns true if it's null.

Now in my view page, I want to use the `"link_to_if"` provided with condition to call the `check_is_null` function from the rails-root/bin folder.

Is it possible?

I'm a learner and google suggestions didn't help!

Method in rails-root/bin/condition.rb

```
def check_is_null(var)
  if var.none?
    @log.info 'Array is null'
    true
  end
end
```

Current View page without using link_to_if:

> link_to "View", result_path(var), target: "_blank"

**Expected result**:

> Link to be disabled when the passed array is null

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in helper file and call that helper method inside the view.